# ListView show only the last item in a list when using DataTemplate

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm binding a customer list to a Xamarin Listview. I want to use a DataTemplate with a ViewCell in it.

As per documentation, we can use one of 2 constructors:

1. new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomerViewCell));
2. new DataTemplate(=>new CustomerViewCell);

However, they lead to different results. The first one correctly displays the list, while the second one shows repeated the last item of the list.

Do I don't know something basic here?

Here's my customer model:

```
 public class Customers : List<Customer>
    {

        public Customers()
        {
            Add(new Customer { No = 1, Name = "Microsoft" });
            Add(new Customer { No = 2, Name = "Google" });
            Add(new Customer { No = 3, Name = "Facebook" });
        }

    }

    public class Customer {

       public int No { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

And here is the CustomerViewCell.xaml, which is inherited from ViewCell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="LVDataTemplate.View.CustomerViewCell">
  <ViewCell.View>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Text="{Binding No}" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackLayout>
  </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

The CustomerListView, which shows the Customers:

```
    public partial class CustomerListView :ContentPage
    {

        public CustomerListView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyListView.ItemsSource = new Customers();

            //1. Work correctly 
            // MyListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomerViewCell));

            //2. Work in-correctly. only the last item repeated through out the list
            var theCell = new CustomerViewCell();
            MyListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>theCell);

        }


    }
```

The first code shows the result:

1. Microsoft.
2. Google
3. Facebook

The second shows

3. Facebook
4. Facebook
5. Facebook

Comment: what specific docs are you reading that show the 2nd format?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the document here: [data-templates/creating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating#creating-a-datatemplate-as-a-resource)

The method `public DataTemplate(Func<object> loadTemplate);` is use to create a datatemplate as a **resource**, so the correct usage of the second constructor is:

```
var personDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {

        return new ViewCell1();
    });


    Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
    Resources.Add("personTemplate", personDataTemplate);

    testListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["personTemplate"];
```

Or you can customize the ViewCell like this:

```
var personDataTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => {
  var grid = new Grid ();
  ...
  return new ViewCell { View = grid };
});
```

Also, you can use personDataTemplate directly without define it as a resource:

```
 testListView.ItemTemplate = personDataTemplate;
```

The problem of your code is you should create theCell inside the block, you can use:

```
    var personDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {

        return new ViewCell1();
    });
```

Or

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
        testListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => test());
    }

    public ViewCell1 test() {

        //other actions
        return new ViewCell1();
    }
}
```

The first constructor  `MyListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomerViewCell));` is [creating-a-datatemplate-with-a-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating#creating-a-datatemplate-with-a-type), that is correct.

Comment: Thank you, Jack Hua. The problem, as you said, is creating the cellview outside of the constructor block.